# What is jQuery's equivalent to Ajax.Request, along with onSuccess and onComplete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs

Here's my code:

```
this.ajax = new Ajax.Request(this.url, {
  method: 'get',
  parameters: { 'timestamp' : this.timestamp },
  onSuccess: function(transport) {
    // handle the server response
    var response = transport.responseText.evalJSON();
    this.comet.timestamp = response['timestamp'];
    this.comet.handleResponse(response);
    this.comet.noerror = true;
  },
  onComplete: function(transport) {
    // send a new ajax request when this request is finished
    if (!this.comet.noerror)
      // if a connection problem occurs, try to reconnect each 5 seconds
      setTimeout(function(){ comet.connect() }, 5000); 
    else
      this.comet.connect();
    this.comet.noerror = false;
  }
});
```

I mainly want to know about the `onComplete` function, that's what I'm pondering over.

Comment: is this so difficult to look up in jQuery API?

Comment: @charlietfl Honestly, it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One such function is `.ajax`. The documentation is quite exhaustive: [jQuery .ajax function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

An example of `onSuccess` and `onComplete`-like functionality might be something like this...

```
$.ajax({
    url: "test.php",
    type: "post",
    data: values,
    success: function() {
        alert("success");
    },
    error: function() {
        alert("failure");
    },
    complete: function() {
        alert("both success and error have been checked, request finished!");
    }
});
```

There are also individual `.post` and `.get` functions, but they are best avoided as they make assumptions about the response, and that can lead to unintended failures.

Comment: ah, ok, I found out for myself.